# Automatic encrypted iPhone backup to Mac (Big Sur)

Tags: mac, backup, itunes, iphone, macos-bigsur

**Context:** Apple does not offer a way to have MacOS *automatically* create encrypted iPhone backups when your iPhone is connected (via cable / WiFi). I *suspect* that Apple is trying to push adoption of iCloud, which unfortunately is not an option for many privacy-aware users, given the lack of iCloud end-to-end encryption. (Apple holds the keys and could read and share your data.)

**Question:** Is there a way to programmatically trigger encrypted iPhone backups, in a way that could be periodically run via cron jobs for example?

I am aware of proprietary/closed source 3rd-party software such as iMazing, but that seems overkill for this very basic task. I'm not willing to add such software to my configuration for sensitive tasks like backups, and there must be a better way.

*PS: "Sync" is not the same as backup, so the auto-sync option won't help here. Sync only copies your iTunes playlists, CD rips, etc.*

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273171/replacing-icloud-on-ios-and-macos-devices-with-a-macos-server-machine

Comment: @not2savvy ... hmm that sounds a bit overkill and it doesn't talk about automatic backups?

Comment: There’s only iTunes and it’s automatic wifi backup but that unfortunately doesn’t work reliably. I don’t understand what’s wrong with s tool like iMazing for you?

Comment: @not2savvy I personally don't like the idea of adding another trusted party to the mix just because Apple decided that we don't deserve E2E encrypted backups. I'll keep looking for another solution.